tkinter and customtkinter Buttons Unresponsive on macOS but Work on Raspberry Pi
I'm working on a Python project using tkinter and customtkinter for the GUI, which will be part of an automated physical chessboard. The issue I'm encountering is that button clicks are not responsive on macOS, even though the same code works perfectly on a Raspberry Pi.
Problem:
On macOS, the buttons often do not respond to clicks.
Adding print statements inside the button callbacks shows that the clicks are not registered at all.
This unresponsiveness occurs even before heavy computations start, suggesting that the issue is not related to threading or processing load.
On Raspberry Pi, everything works as expected, with buttons responding immediately to clicks.
Additional Information:
I am a beginner in Python.
I decided to switch to customtkinter in the middle of development, so there is a mix of tkinter and customtkinter in my code. I apologize for the mess.
When I write a simple program with just one button in customtkinter that prints a message to the screen, it works perfectly. This suggests there is an issue with my code.
However, the fact that everything works on Raspberry Pi but not on macOS suggests the issue might be related to the operating system, which is confusing.
`
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import font as tkfont
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from main import start_game
from chessboard import ChessBoard
import threading

class ChessApp(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, update_label_callback, update_eval_bar_callback, update_best_moves_callback):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Scacchi")
        self.geometry("600x1000")
        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        ctk.set_default_color_theme("green")
        self.update_label_callback = update_label_callback
        self.update_eval_bar_callback = update_eval_bar_callback
        self.update_best_moves_callback = update_best_moves_callback
        self.start_page = StartPage(self)
        self.difficulty_page = DifficultyPage(self)
        self.game_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self)
        self.chessboard = ChessBoard(self.game_frame)
        self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.game_frame, text="", bg_color="grey", text_color="black", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=18))

        # Labels per le migliori mosse
        self.first_move_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.game_frame, text="", text_color="white", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=18))
        self.second_move_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.game_frame, text="", text_color="white", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=18))
        self.third_move_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.game_frame, text="", text_color="white", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=18))

        # Pulsanti
        self.toggle_eval_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.game_frame, text="Toggle Eval Bar", command=self.toggle_eval_bar)
        self.toggle_best_moves_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.game_frame, text="Toggle Best Moves", command=self.toggle_best_moves)

        self.eval_bar = ctk.CTkCanvas(self.game_frame, width=512, height=20, bg="white")
        self.show_eval_bar = False
        self.show_best_moves = False

        self.start_page.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.update_gui()
        self.resizable(False, False)

    def show_start_page(self):
        self.difficulty_page.pack_forget()
        self.game_frame.pack_forget()
        self.start_page.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def show_difficulty_page(self):
        self.start_page.pack_forget()
        self.game_frame.pack_forget()
        self.difficulty_page.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.difficulty_page.focus_set()

    def show_game_page(self, difficulty):
        self.difficulty_page.pack_forget()
        self.start_page.pack_forget()
        self.game_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.label.pack(fill="x")
        self.toggle_eval_button.pack(side="bottom")
        self.toggle_best_moves_button.pack(side="bottom")
        self.chessboard.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.update_label("waiting for first move")
        threading.Thread(target=start_game, args=(self.update_label_callback, self.update_eval_bar, difficulty, self.chessboard, self.update_best_moves_callback)).start()

    def update_label(self, text):
        self.label.configure(text=text)

    def toggle_eval_bar(self):
        self.show_eval_bar = not self.show_eval_bar
        if self.show_eval_bar:
            self.eval_bar.place(relx=0.5, y=562, width=512, height=20, anchor='n')
            self.eval_bar.create_rectangle(0, 0, 256, 20, fill="black", outline="black")
            self.eval_bar.create_rectangle(256, 0, 512, 20, fill="white", outline="black")
        else:
            self.eval_bar.place_forget()

    def toggle_best_moves(self):
        self.show_best_moves = not self.show_best_moves
        if self.show_best_moves:
            self.first_move_label.pack()
            self.second_move_label.pack()
            self.third_move_label.pack()
        else:
            self.first_move_label.pack_forget()
            self.second_move_label.pack_forget()
            self.third_move_label.pack_forget()

    def update_eval_bar(self, eval_score):
        if not self.show_eval_bar:
            return
        self.eval_bar.delete("eval")
        middle_x = 256
        if eval_score > 0:
            eval_width = min(512, middle_x * eval_score / 10)
            self.eval_bar.create_rectangle(middle_x - eval_width, 0, middle_x, 20, fill="white",
                                           outline="grey", tags="eval")
        else:
            eval_width = min(512, middle_x * abs(eval_score) / 10)
            self.eval_bar.create_rectangle(middle_x, 0, middle_x + eval_width, 20, fill="black",
                                           outline="grey", tags="eval")

    def update_best_moves(self, moves):
        if not self.show_best_moves:
            return
        self.first_move_label.configure(text=moves[0] if len(moves) > 0 else "")
        self.second_move_label.configure(text=moves[1] if len(moves) > 1 else "")
        self.third_move_label.configure(text=moves[2] if len(moves) > 2 else "")

    def update_gui(self):
        self.after(100, self.update_gui)


class StartPage(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(bg_color="white")

        # Carica l'immagine
        img = Image.open("images/chesslogo.png")
        img = img.resize((180, 180), Image.LANCZOS)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        # Crea un CTkLabel con l'immagine come sfondo
        image_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, image=self.image, text="")

        # Posiziona l'immagine in alto al centro
        image_label.pack(side="top", pady=20)

        pvc = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Player vs computer", text_color="white", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=14),
                            command=master.show_difficulty_page, width=300)
        pvc.pack(pady=20)  # Aggiungi fill="x" per espandere il pulsante orizzontalmente

        pvp = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Player vs Player", text_color="white", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=14),
                            command=master.show_difficulty_page, width=300)
        pvp.pack(pady=20)  # Aggiungi fill="x" per espandere il pulsante orizzontalmente


class DifficultyPage(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(bg_color="grey")

        self.title = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Select difficulty", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=20), text_color="white")
        self.title.pack(pady=20)

        self.goback = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Go back", text_color="white", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=14), command=master.show_start_page)
        self.goback.pack(pady=20)
        self.buttons = [
            self.create_button("Easy", 1),
            self.create_button("Medium", 10),
            self.create_button("Hard", 20)
        ]
        self.current_button_index = 0

        self.buttons[self.current_button_index].focus_set()
        for button in self.buttons:
            button.bind("<Up>", self.move_focus_up)
            button.bind("<Down>", self.move_focus_down)
            button.bind("<Return>", self.select_button)
        self.focus_set()

        self.highlight_button(self.current_button_index)

    def create_button(self, text, difficulty):
        button = ctk.CTkButton(self, text=text, command=lambda: self.master.show_game_page(difficulty), font=ctk.CTkFont(size=18))
        button.pack(pady=20)
        return button

    def highlight_button(self, index):
        for i, btn in enumerate(self.buttons):
            if i == index:
                btn.configure(fg_color="yellow")
            else:
                btn.configure(fg_color="grey")

    def move_focus_up(self, event):
        self.current_button_index = (self.current_button_index - 1) % len(self.buttons)
        self.highlight_button(self.current_button_index)

    def move_focus_down(self, event):
        self.current_button_index = (self.current_button_index + 1) % len(self.buttons)
        self.highlight_button(self.current_button_index)

    def select_button(self, event):
        self.buttons[self.current_button_index].invoke()
        return "break"


def update_label(text):
    app.update_label(text)


def update_eval_bar(eval_score):
    app.update_eval_bar(eval_score)

def update_best_moves(moves):
    app.update_best_moves(moves)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ChessApp(update_label, update_eval_bar, update_best_moves)
    app.mainloop()


note that you can run the file eliminating the lines calling the other files.
`
Threading: Implemented threading to ensure that heavy computations are not blocking the main thread.
Event Binding: Checked and ensured that events are properly bound to buttons.
Focus Handling: Verified that buttons are getting proper focus.
Updating Libraries: All libraries (tkinter, customtkinter, and dependencies) are up-to-date.
Using tkmacosx: Considered but didn't fully integrate as the issue persisted.
Despite these attempts, the problem remains unresolved on macOS. Below is a simplified version of my code. I apologize if the code is a bit messy, as I am still a beginner in Python.

line 4, in 
from main import start_game
ImportError: cannot import name 'start_game' from 'main' (C:\Users\Afraz\Documents\python3_dummy\tmp_dummy\main.py)
